# Avoiding numerical overflow when calculating the value AND gradient of the Logistic loss function

Tags: matlab, floating-point, numerical-methods, logistic-regression, numerical-stability

I am currently trying to implement a machine learning algorithm that involves the [logistic loss function](http://www.hongliangjie.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/logistic.pdf) in MATLAB. Unfortunately, I am having some trouble due to numerical overflow.

In general, for a given an input `s`,  the value of the logistic function is:

```
 log(1 + exp(s))
```

and the slope of the logistic loss function is:

```
 exp(s)./(1 + exp(s)) = 1./(1 + exp(-s))
```

In my algorithm, the value of `s = X*beta`. Here `X` is a matrix with `N` data points and `P` features per data point (i.e. `size(X)=[N,P]`) and `beta` is a vector of `P` coefficients for each feature such that `size(beta)=[P 1]`.

I am specifically interested in calculating the average value and gradient of the Logistic function for given value of `beta`.

The average value of the Logistic function w.r.t to a value of `beta` is:

```
 L = 1/N * sum(log(1+exp(X*beta)),1)
```

The average value of the slope of the Logistic function w.r.t. to a value of `b` is:

```
 dL = 1/N * sum((exp(X*beta)./(1+exp(X*beta))' X, 1)'
```

Note that `size(dL) = [P 1].`

My issue is that these expressions keep producing numerical overflows. The problem effectively comes from the fact that `exp(s)=Inf` when `s>1000` and `exp(s)=0` when `s<-1000.`

I am looking for a solution such that `s` can take on any value in floating point arithmetic. Ideally, I would also really appreciate a solution that allows me to evaluate the value and gradient in a vectorized / efficient way.

Comment: There are two files I know which may solve both of your problems. See [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36534-hpf-a-big-decimal-class) for high precision floating point. See [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725-variable-precision-integer-arithmetic) for handling arbitrarily large numbers

Comment: Berk U.: Did one of the answers help you?

Comment: @A.Donda They were insightful but did not handle the underflow issue. I found another answer which I will post soon!

Comment: Hm, but I gave approximations for both large and small s, so that underflow could be avoided. If not, please comment in detail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about the following approximations:

– For computing `L`, if `s` is large, then `exp(s)` will be much larger than 1:

```
1 + exp(s) ≅ exp(s)
```

and consequently

```
log(1 + exp(s)) ≅ log(exp(s)) = s.
```

If `s` is small, then using the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of exp()

```
exp(s) ≅ 1 + s
```

and using the Taylor series of log()

```
log(1 + exp(s)) ≅ log(2 + s) ≅ log(2) + s / 2.
```

– For computing `dL`, for large `s`

```
exp(s) ./ (1 + exp(s)) ≅ 1
```

and for small `s`

```
exp(s) ./ (1 + exp(s)) ≅ 1/2 + s / 4.
```

– The code to compute `L` could look for example like this:

```
s = X*beta;
l = log(1+exp(s));
ind = isinf(l);
l(ind) = s(ind);
ind = (l == 0);
l(ind) = log(2) + s(ind) / 2;
L = 1/N * sum(l,1)
```

Comment: Bingo.  You can actually get rigorous bounds on how big s needs to be for your second equality to hold in floating-point arithmetic.  (Which is, of course, totally overkill, but it provides a very solid justification for why it's legitimate to do so.)

Comment: @tmyklebu, interesting, didn't think of that.

Answer (score 5):

I found [a good article about this problem](https://web.archive.org/web/20140221080116/http://lingpipe-blog.com/2012/02/16/howprevent-overflow-underflow-logistic-regression).

Cutting through a lot of words, we can simplify the argument to stating that the original expression

```
log(1 + exp(s))
```

can be rewritten as

```
log(exp(s)*(exp(-s) + 1))
= log(exp(s)) + log(exp(-s) + 1)
= s + log(exp(-s) + 1)
```

This stops overflow from occurring - it doesn't prevent underflow, but by the time that occurs, you have your answer (namely, `s`). You can't just use this instead of the original, since it will still give you problems. However, we now have the basis for a function that can be written that will be accurate and won't produce over/underflow:

```
function LL = logistic(s)
if s<0
  LL = log(1 + exp(s));
else
  LL = s + logistic(-s);
```

I think this maintains reasonably good accuracy.

**EDIT** now to the meat of your question - making this vectorized, and allowing the calculation of the slope as well. Let's take these one at a time:

```
function LL = logisticVec(s)
  LL = zeros(size(s));
  LL(s<0) = log(1 + exp(s(s<0)));
  LL(s>=0) = s(s>=0) + log(1 + exp(-s(s>=0)));
```

To obtain the average you wanted:

```
L = logisticVec(X*beta) / N;
```

The slope is a little bit trickier; note I believe you may have a typo in your expression (missing a multiplication sign).

```
dL/dbeta = sum(X * exp(X*beta) ./ (1 + exp(X*beta))) / N;
```

If we divide top and bottom by `exp(X*beta)` we get

```
dL = sum(X ./ (exp(-X*beta) + 1)) / N;
```

Once again, the overflow has gone away and we are left with underflow - but since the underflowed value has `1` added to it, the error this creates is insignificant.

Comment: You need to handle the case where s is very negative, too, and you run into exactly the same issue there.

Comment: Yep. This is basically [log sum of exponentials](http://www.hongliangjie.com/2011/01/07/logsum/).