# Numpy/Cython: how to create a memory view of user-defined columns of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, cython, linear-algebra, blas

[I am currently working on improving the runtime for a simple Cython function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35303759/what-is-causing-the-2x-slowdown-in-my-cython-implementation-of-matrix-vector-mul) to multiply a numpy matrix `A` and a numpy vector `x` using BLAS (i.e. runs `A.dot.x` in normal numpy)

My current implementation `matrix_multiply(A,x)` does this without copying the data:

```
import cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport scipy.linalg.cython_blas as blas

DTYPE = np.float64
ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_T

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)

def matrix_multiply(np.ndarray[DTYPE_T, ndim=2, mode="fortran"] A, np.ndarray[DTYPE_T, ndim=1, mode="fortran"] x):
    #calls dgemv from BLAS which computes y = alpha * trans(A) + beta * y
    #see: http://www.nag.com/numeric/fl/nagdoc_fl22/xhtml/F06/f06paf.xml

    cdef int N = A.shape[0]
    cdef int D = A.shape[1]
    cdef int lda = N
    cdef int incx = 1 #increments of x
    cdef int incy = 1 #increments of y
    cdef double alpha = 1.0
    cdef double beta = 0.0
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_T, ndim=1, mode = "fortran"] y = np.empty(N, dtype = DTYPE)

    blas.dgemv("N", &N, &D, &alpha, &A[0,0], &lda, &x[0], &incx, &beta, &y[0], &incy)

    return y
```

**I am wondering how I can change this so that it computes `A(:,selected).dot.x` instead of `A.dot.x`, where `selected` is a set of ordered indices of the columns.**

I am open to any implementation, though I suppose that the easiest way would be to change the function header to `matrix_multiply(A,x,selected)` so it also expects `selected` as an input. I believe that the answer has to use memory views, but I am not sure.

Comment: Ultimately `dgemv` expects a pointer to an F-contiguous matrix, so there's no way you're going to be able to use it to compute the dot between multiple non-contiguous columns in `A` and your vector without generating a copy first. The best you could do without creating a copy would be to loop over your selected columns `A[:, i]`, compute their inner products with `x`, and accumulate the results in another vector `y[i]`.